# how to get one click - after click nested li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem to identify clicked li element, her is html structure:

```
<section class="right_menu" id="right_menu">
<div class="menu_pusher">

   <ul id="0">
    <li><a href="#">Product_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product_3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product_4</a></li>
    <li class="Product_5"><a href="#">Product_5</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="Article_1"><a href="#">Article_1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Detail_1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Detail_2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Detail_3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Article_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Article_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Article_4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Product_4</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</section>
```

So when i click in Product_5 alert give me Product_5 and so is ok but when I clikc then in Article_1 alert give me Article_1 and then Product_5 agein, it look like double click but I dont now way.

This is javascript code:

```
    function has_ul(element){
    if((element.getElementsByTagName('li').length >= 1))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{   $('#right_menu .menu_pusher ul li').on('click',rout);})

var timeout      = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem    = 0,
open = false;

function rout(){open?jsddm_close():jsddm_open(this);}

function jsddm_open(el)
{   
//open=true;
jsddm_canceltimer();

    if(has_ul(el)){
        var lef = parseInt($('.menu_pusher').css("left")) - 220;
        alert(el.className);
        $('.menu_pusher').css('left', lef);
        return false;
    }
}

function jsddm_close()
{   

if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('display', 'none');
open=false;}

function jsddm_timer()
{   closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{   if(closetimer)
    {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;}}
```

So way I get to li element click? Here is link to this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/rwqc9bje/

Comment: Sorry - So way I get two li element click? this question is correct

Comment: You need to pass event variable to your click functions and call event.stopPropagation(), so it wouldn't bubble up and call the click handlers of the parent li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handle the event on a element instead of li...  This should avoid having this double event behavior.

Comment: in what way? Can you give an example

Comment: Try to change J query selector to be:$('#right_menu .menu_pusher ul li a')

Comment: Ok, but when I do this I have to get li element in what way

Comment: Well try this:$('#right_menu .menu_pusher ul li a').on('click', function() { rout($(this).closest('li')); } );})  you have then to modify rout function  and add parameter to it which is the li element.

Comment: ok I tray this and I get not li element but Object is possible to convert it to li element